# AWS Glue failed to insert UUID into Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, aws-glue, uuid

I created a table in Aurora Postgres DB with one UUID column `id`, and created a AWS Glue Studio
Job with the following code:

```py
schema = ['id']
rdd = [[str(uuid.uuid4())]]
dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_rdd(rdd, 'dyf', schema=schema)
glueContext.write_from_options(frame_or_dfc=dyf, connection_type='postgresql', connection_options={...})
```

An error was reported:

> 2023-01-05 20:27:35,757 INFO [task-result-getter-0]
> scheduler.TaskSetManager (Logging.scala:logInfo(57)): Lost task 35.1
> in stage 0.0 (TID 36) on 10.248.10.50, executor 1:
> java.sql.BatchUpdateException (Batch entry 0 INSERT INTO "data"."t"
> ("id") VALUES ('6f2ac9cd-c6a9-4798-bc9b-59c8a3d37ca1') was aborted:
> ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type character
> varying   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.

I tried `rdd = [[uuid.uuid4()]]`, but it seems Spark doesn't support `uuid`.

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

```sql
INSERT INTO "data"."t" ("id") VALUES ('6f2ac9cd-c6a9-4798-bc9b-59c8a3d37ca1')
```

The weird thing is I can run the SQL statement successfully from a SQL client. Is it a bug in AWS Glue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by adding an item to the `connection_options`

```py
connection_options = {
    ...
    'stringtype': 'unspecified',
}
```

But it still doesn't support inserting NULL values into UUID columns. A workaround would be inserting 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 instead.

Comment: can you explain why it doesn't support inserting NULL?